# CMS homepage doesn't display if Page url key is changed

Tags: magento-1.9

I am unable to change the Page URL key for the homepage. If, I change it anything else, the homepage doesn't display. I don't really like the theme name to show as the Homepage URL key.
Here is a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the URL Key, you need to update the value of `System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page`